# Post condition failed when trying to open personalization

Tags: experience-editor, personalization

We have a Tabs rendering which is a composite, when I clicked the personalization button on the rendering's toolbar it threw an exception:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Post condition failed]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ResultNotNull(T result, String message) +85
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Dialogs.Personalization.PersonalizationForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +208

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +132
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +599
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +154
```

This does not happen on non-composite renderings, only on composite renderings. I don't know if I have explained my scenario properly, so please do ask some questions if there are other things that could help me in determining the cause. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check your logs under App_Data/logs/log.[YYYYMMDD].txt?

Comment: @PaulsonMaclean yes, the same message is shown on the logs. No more than that.

Comment: I will be waiting here for an answer as well and this is still an issue.